# Symfony2 getting value of disabled form fields (or marking them all as not disabled)

Tags: forms, symfony

I have a situation where in my twig I dynamically set some form fields to disabled or not.

When I submit I need all fields to be enabled, otherwise the field value is null (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857045/symfony2-disabled-select) for a similar issue). My problem is that my form is more complex than the one in the example.

Here it is:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class HRMgmtFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$rolesListForForm = $options['data']['rolesListForForm'];
$HRsInThisProject = $options['data']['HRsInThisProject'];
$HRsInMyDomainForForm = $options['data']['HRsInMyDomainForForm'];    

$builder->add('showinactive', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Show inactive users', 'required'  => false, 'data' => true, ));
foreach ($HRsInThisProject as $key => $HR)
    {
    $builder->add('roleOf_'.$key, 'choice', array('choices'   => $rolesListForForm, 'required'  => true, 'data' => $HR['role'], 'label' => false, ))
            ->add('isActive_'.$key, 'choice', array('choices'   => [0 => 'Inactive', 1 => 'Active'] , 'required'  => true, 'data' => $HR['is_active'], 'label' => false, ));
    }
$builder->add('HRid', 'choice', array('choices' => $HRsInMyDomainForForm,'required' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Choose a resource', 'label' => false, ));
$builder->add('role', 'choice', array('choices' => $rolesListForForm,'required' => false, 'placeholder' => 'Choose a role', 'label' => false, ));            
$builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));  

//this is what is suggested in the link I mentioned
$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event) {
            $event->getForm()->add( // some stuff //, array(
                // more stuff //
                'disabled' => false
            ));
        }
    );
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'MRMgmt';
}
}
```

In my twig I do something like:

```
{% for key, HR in HRs %}
...
{% if role.OthersProfileChangeSecurityRightsRoles %}
   {{ form_row(form['roleOf_' ~ key]) }}
{% else %}
   {{ form_row(form['roleOf_' ~ key], { 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
{% endif %}
```

I was wondering: is there a way to solve the issue in another way?
Or can I iterate over all the fields and mark them as 'disabled'=>false without the need of basically recreating the whole form which seems an overkill (and I don't know if I still have access to all the variables I need to do it)?
Maybe a workaround would be creating hidden fields instead of disabled fields, and print in my twig the value of the field instead of a field that is disabled...

Thank you!

Comment: If you make the fields hidden you shouldn't have to add any extra Twig code.  You could also set the 'readonly' HTML5 attribute although that's less safe.

Comment: In the end I managed it with hidden forms. I have to modify slightly my twig as I need to show the value of the field (even if the field is not editable), but it's a minor hassle.